# Не работает USB-адаптер Bluetooth на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

Моя система - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Раньше была система Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, тоже не работал Bluetooth-адаптер. Адаптер не видит устройства, но убунту вроде видит сам адаптер. Что выводят команды чтобы получить всю необходимую информацию:

```
nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ rfkill list
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 045e:07f8 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600 (model 1576)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b3f:2247 Generalplus Technology Inc. GENERAL WEBCAM
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ lsmod | grep btusb
btusb 61440 0
btrtl 24576 1 btusb
btbcm 20480 1 btusb
btintel 32768 1 btusb
bluetooth 651264 12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ bluetoothctl list
ничего не вывело.

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable>
Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-04-17 16:57:17 EEST; 37min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 3712 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
Tasks: 1 (limit: 9012)
Memory: 508.0K
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
└─3712 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop bluetoothd[3712]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop bluetoothd[3712]: Starting SDP server
апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop bluetoothd[3712]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initi>
lines 1-16/16 (END)

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[sudo] пароль для nikita: 
[    4.056484] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.056518] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.056519] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.056523] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.056525] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.056528] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.127457] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[    5.021806] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.021809] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.021811] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.256951] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[   11.272147] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
```

Моя версия ядра: 5.17.4

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос вывод команды `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`. Там наверняка будет что-то об ошибках Bluetooth.

Comment: Добавил, там какие-то ошибки.

Comment: Именно эту ошибку вам нужно погуглить, чтобы найти патч для ядра, который её обходит.

Comment: Я не знаю как загуглить, когда мне непонятна ошибка. Можете найти этот патч, пожалуйста?